# SQL Outer join 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `comp_product` and `comp_product_marchand`.

The `comp_product` contains product information (description, name, etc..)

The `comp_product_marchand` contains different prices (product resellers). Each reseller has a price for a product. But not for all products

I would like to get in only one SQL Query for each reseller the list of products and his price (even if the reseller doesn't have one)

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    p.id_product,
    pm.price
FROM comp_product_marchand pm
LEFT OUTER JOIN comp_product p
    ON p.id_product = pm.id_product
WHERE id_marchand = 4
```

(WHERE clause is for demo only)

This SQL Query returns the price for products which have a price, not the others... 
Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle

Comment: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/936101Sanstitre.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your link between table:

```
SELECT
    p.id_product,
    pm.price
FROM comp_product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN comp_product_marchand pm
    ON p.id_product = pm.id_product
    AND id_marchand = 4
```

In this way you'll show all product and if the marchand = 4 has one the info about marchand will be showed.

I put the query on marchand ID in the ON clause because if you put it in the WHERE clause you'll cut all lines where the marchand has no that product

Comment: +1 : This answer also reversed the order of the query from `price LEFT JOIN product` (as in the OP's post) to `product LEFT JOIN price`, thus ensuring that all products are always included in the results of the JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the way the join operates. You can either use your currently query and use a `RIGHT`join, or the way I prefer is to switch the order of the tables (still using a `LEFT` join) so the table you wish to see all results for is on the left side of the join. Sometimes a difficult concept but this diagram can help

[image]

Code for switching join:
     SELECT 
         p.id_product, 
         pm.price

```
    FROM comp_product p
               LEFT OUTER JOIN comp_product_marchand pm ON 
                               p.id_product=pm.id_product 
                               AND id_marchand=4 ;
```

Comment: You can't put in WHERE clause id_marchand = 4 because when comp_product_marchand not exists in this way you cut that rows

Comment: I assumed this was just filtering for that merchant? So his query only returns prices and products for once merchant.

Comment: Thanks for helping, your diagram will help me a lot ! ;)

Comment: @Telexx: Hi, our OP wants all products of that marchant but if the marchant has not product, he wants to show that product.

Comment: @Telexx: Fix your answer, +1 for detailed JOIN explanation